# Integrating Sikuli script with Jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, batch-file, jenkins, sikuli

I have created an automation project in eclipse using selenium webdriver and sikuli. I have created a testng.xml file to run it. When I run the script using Eclipse, it is running fine. When I created a bat file, then also it is running fine. But when I integrate it with Jenkins and run the bat file through it is showing following error:

> ```
> [error] Location: outside any screen (16699376, 0) - subsequent actions might not work as expected
> [error] Location: outside any screen (16699600, 0) - subsequent actions might not work as expected
> [error] Location: outside any screen (16699600, 0) - subsequent actions might not work as expected
> [error] Location: outside any screen (16699312, 0) - subsequent actions might not work as expected
> [error] RobotDesktop: checkMousePosition: should be L(16699600,0)
> but after move is L(16699312,0)
> ```

Possible cause in case you did not touch the mouse while script was running:

> ```
> Mouse actions are blocked generally or by the frontmost application.
> You might try to run the SikuliX stuff as admin.
> ```

Please help me with a detailed description.

Comment: You expect a solution with a detailed description, but you are not willing to provide a detalied description about what you are trying to accomplish and how you want to achieve that.

Comment: Hi...i have already explained the whole outline of the project...what else do I need to provide to solve the problem?